# Win32 Default Height of Edit Control

Tags: winapi, controls, createwindow

I'm using `CreateWindowEx` to create an Edit control (a textbox), but saying `CW_DEFAULT` doesn't help with getting the default height of the textbox -- it just makes a window with a height of zero.

How do I get the system-default size of a textbox, so I can turn Edit control into a normal-looking textbox?

Comment: That is the documented behavior: ["if `CW_USEDEFAULT` is specified for a pop-up or child window, the *nWidth* and *nHeight* parameters are set to zero."](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632680.aspx).  So `CW_USEDEFAULT` is definitely the wrong approach.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The recommended size is 14 dialog units.  [Here is the reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742486.aspx#sizingandspacing)

You can use [`MapDialogRect`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645502.aspx) to convert dialog units into pixels.

Comment: Is there any way to get this programmatically? Or do I need to hard-code it into my program?

Comment: You mean the 14 dialog units, or the number of pixels.  Dialog units are defined in terms of the height of a line of text, so that number should be hard-coded.  As I said, you then use `MapDialogRect` to convert to pixels, taking into account the user settings for font size and monitor DPI.